# Confirm dialog inject it or hide it (performance)

Tags: angular, dom

I wrote a little confirm dialog component, i attach it to the DOM, in my app.component.html

> ```
> <app-confirm-dialog></app-confirm-dialog>
> ```

The component shows up when I call the service methode

active('', '').

```
    ﻿import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ConfirmDialogService
{

  activate: (message?: string, title?: string) => Promise<boolean>;

  constructor() { }

}
```

As I userstand the code for my app-confirm-dialog is attached and is listening to changes, which isn't very good for the performance.

Is it better to inject it dynamicaly or is it ok to attach it already while *ngIf=false?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case - if you assume the Confirmation Dialog is a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) then dependency injection would be the way to go. (this is a pretty safe assumption for a confirmation dialog - doubt you would ever have more than one instance)

On the other hand if for some reason you wanted to have multiple confirmation dialogs on the screen you be forced to use`ngIf`.

Remember `ngIf` actually prevents elements from existing in the DOM when the condition is false - this means their component logic is not listening for changes so you might want to consider that.

Regardless I don't think you'd notice much performance difference for something as minuscule as this.